# phantomjs cannot find node module 'crypto' while accessing aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, phantomjs, node-modules

I have an application which is using phantom js and nodejs app. I am using several node modules in that node app, which is run through phantom js. I need to use amazon node aws-sdk. I installed it with

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

that node app is able to find that once i do this

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

but it start prompting errors for other native node js modules, three of them specifically, 'crypto', 'timers', 'path'. I checked /usr/lib/nodejs folder and those are there, so how come phantomjs node app is unable to find them?
specific errors

```
Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'
 phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:299 in require
 phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:263 in require
 phantomjs://platform/util.js:4
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'AWS.util.update')

 phantomjs://platform/core.js:16
Error: Cannot find module 'path'

 phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:299 in require
 phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:263 in require
 phantomjs://platform/api_loader.js:3
Error: Cannot find module 'events'

 phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:299 in require
 phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:263 in require
 phantomjs://platform/xml2js.js:12
 phantomjs://platform/xml2js.js:538
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'AWS.XML.Parser = require('./xml/node_parser')')
```

it does work fine if i directly go to node shell and do require('aws-sdk').
i run node app from phantomjs like this

```
phantomjs test.js
```

or

```
/usr/bin/phantomjs test.js
```

it just doesn't work with phantomjs, any idea and help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 3):

PhantomJS is not compatible with node.js.

When you run it like

```
/usr/bin/phantomjs test.js
```

you run a script inside of PhantomJS.

If you want to launch a node.js app from PhantomJS, you can use exec or spawn methods to do it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992664/2715393)