# How to invoke PhantomJS commands from NodeJs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have a Node Server and I need to call some PhantomJS commands from NodeJS server. Like this command.

> phantomjs phantom-server.js http://example.com

I got some answers on this topic on the following question. But it's not so clear what are the arguments I have to pass for that.

[Is it possible to run PhantomJS from node.js as a command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259818/is-it-possible-to-run-phantomjs-from-node-js-as-a-command-line-argument)

In this example there's a line like folloes.

> 'some other argument (passed to phantomjs script)'

And I can't figure it out what to pass there.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33992664/2715393

Comment: Besides the direct Phantomjs process execution, it is possible to use server module to directly communicate with the server process http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/method/listen.html

Answer (score 0):

It means that in the childArgs array, other than the path to your phantomjs script, you can also add the arguments required by your script. So if you wanted to execute

```
phantomjs phantom-server.js http://example.com
```

you would pass the string `'http://example.com'` along with your script's path.